# DB2 - Concat all values in a column into a Single string

Tags: db2

Let's say I have a table like this:
**test**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 2 |

I am doing query select col1 from test where col2 = 1;
This will return a column with values A B and C in 3 separate rows.
I want the SQL to return a single row with value `A|B|C`. Is this possible to do? If it is how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use LISTAGG function like this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(col1, ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `LISTAGG` is not available, it can be reproduced with `XMLAGG`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(XMLSERIALIZE(XMLAGG(XMLTEXT('|'||"Col1"))),2)  
FROM "test"
WHERE "Col2" = 1
```